# Extracting hours and minutes from UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, swift3, uidatepicker

I have a UIDatePicker set in time mode, and have a property referencing that date picker. I don't know how to extract hour and minutes components from UIDatePicker when set to time mode in Swift 3.
Please help

Comment: the picker has the `date:Date` property. So the question would be "Getting hour and minute from Date", and that is answered many times.

Answer (score 23):

Even in `.time` mode the `date` property returns a `Date` instance.

Get hour and minute with `Calendar` and `DateComponents`

```
let picker = UIDatePicker()
picker.datePickerMode = .time

let date = picker.date
let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: date)
let hour = components.hour!
let minute = components.minute!
```